# Silvelight&RIA Services&Entity Framework problems with partial classes and complex types there

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA Services with Entity Framework and Silverlight as the client Application. I've got some custom properties for EF Entity through partial class. There is a field in Database with XML type and it's mapped to Entity Framework as string. And I use partial class to deserialize this xml string to real object.

This is the partial class for EF Configuration Entity:

```
public partial class Configuration
{
    private ServiceCredentials _serviceCredentialsObject;

    [DataMember]
    public ServiceCredentials ServiceCredentialsObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this._serviceCredentialsObject
                   ?? (this._serviceCredentialsObject = this.DeserializeServiceCredentialsToObject());
        }

        set
        {
            this._serviceCredentialsObject = value;
            this.SerializeServiceCredentialsObject();
        }
    }

    public ServiceCredentials DeserializeServiceCredentialsToObject()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ServiceCredentials))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var result = XmlSerializerHelper.Deserialize<ServiceCredentials>(this.ServiceCredentials);
        result.FileEncoding = result.FileEncoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;

        return result;
    }

    public void SerializeServiceCredentialsObject()
    {
        if (this.ServiceCredentialsObject == null)
        {
            this.ServiceCredentials = null;
            return;
        }

        this.ServiceCredentials = XmlSerializerHelper.Serialize(this.ServiceCredentialsObject);
    }

}
```

And this is the object i'm trying to Deserialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class ServiceCredentials
{

    public NetworkCredential Credential { get; set; }

    public Encoding FileEncoding { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public long HistoryID { get; set; }

    public string LoadFileStoragePath { get; set; }

    public string ManualLoadFilePath { get; set; }

    public bool NeedAuthorization { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }

    public string SourceUrl { get; set; }

    public bool AutomaticTransferToProductive { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to use Configuration Entity on silverlight client-side with generated code find an issue that there is no ServiceCredentialsObject in Configuration class. And it's not added to DomainService.metadata.cs if i create new one. If i add ServiceCredentialsObject to DomainService.metadata.cs manually i can access it on clien-side after rebuild but i can find only properties with simple types there. For example a can acess HistoryID,SourceUrl,AutomaticTransferToProductive but there are no generated properties for

public NetworkCredential Credential { get; set; }
  public Encoding FileEncoding { get; set; }

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the only way to solve this problem. The solution was just to deserialize xml field from entity framework on client-side. I've created partial class Configuration for generated code in silverlight. I don't know if it's the best solution but it works.